# Change iOS 10 web app status bar

Tags: ios, web-applications, statusbar, html-framework-7

I'm working on a web app for **iOS 10** (using **Framework 7**) and I would like to change the default black color of the **status bar**.

I tried this:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
```

But it's not working... How can I do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the CSS

```
.statusbar-overlay {
background: black;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To get a light status bar with black text, use:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">
```

To get a black status bar with white text, use:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">
```

To get transparent statusbar with white text, use:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
```

See [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW1)

If you would like a semi transparent statusbar, you can add a 20px high bar fixed to the top of the page. I would do a query though to check whether the app is in full screen mode: You can determine whether a webpage is displayed in full-screen mode using the window.navigator.standalone read-only Boolean JavaScript property.

I haven't tested this though.